# How to show pdf page wise in android

Tags: android

How to show pdf page wise in android.

I have a PDF of multiple pages but can't show it as combined in android can any one please help me.

Comment: What have you got already? What are you exactly trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Intents** to show a PDF document in your application. Here's the excellent [sample](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/09/sharing-project-assets-with-android-intents.html).